# Не работает margin auto по вертикали

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Есть фрагмент кода

```
            <div className="bg">
                    <div className="row justify-content-center row-enter">
                        <form className="enter justify-content-center">

                        </form>
                    </div>
                <div className="text">
                    <h3 id='powered-by'>Powered by</h3>
                    <h3 id='uni-groups'>Company</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
```

У этих элементов есть следующие свойства:

```
.bg {
/* The image used */
background-image: url("img/BG.jpg");

/* Full height */
height: 100%;

/* Center and scale the image nicely */
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

.enter {
    width: 435px;
    height: 477px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 445px !important;
}

.text {
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto 0 0 auto;
}
```

Все остальное - обычные стили бутстрапа 4.
Не могу разместить div с классом `text` в нижнем правом углу так, чтобы он всегда был в этой позиции при изменении размеров окна.
 Конкретно проблема состоит в том, что  этот  стиль:

```
.text {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

почему-то не применяется.

[image: Проблема с неработающим верхним margin: auto]

Comment: float:right; попробуйте

Comment: код пришли страницы, так чтобы его запустить можно было.

Answer (score 0):

margin так не работает, можно попробовать так

```css
.text {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto 0 0 auto;
}

.align-items-center {
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}

.d-flex {
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="text d-flex align-items-center">
  <div>
    <h3 id='powered-by'>Powered by Company</h3> 
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]